# How can I draw the stream of a camera on a Silverlight control - Metro & Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have a tablet with Windows 8 installed and I want to create a Metro-Application.
I have a front-facing and a back-facing camera. I'd like to draw the camera stream of any of these sources on a Silverlight rectangle. For Windows Phone 7 I can do that with a `VideoBrush` in a `Rectangle`.
How does that work on Windows 8?
And I'm not talking about making pictures with the `CameraCaptureUI`class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I just found a similar question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469011/how-to-get-camera-feeds-in-windows-8-metro-style-app):

the answer for my problem is this:

`<CaptureElement x:Name="captureElement"/>`

```
async private void StartCamPrev()
{
    var mediaCapture = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture();
    await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();
    this.captureElement.Source = mediaCapture;
    await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
}
```

And the answer about the front-face/back-face camera I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136634/how-to-switch-between-webcams-when-using-captureelement-mediacapture):

```
DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
var mediaCapture = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture();
await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
{
    // the index of the devices-array is defining the device
    // here I just put a '0' for testing-purposes:
    VideoDeviceId = devices[0].Id
});
```